# Nginx redirect wp-admin in root to wp-admin in subfolder

Tags: nginx, redirect, wordpress

I'm running a multisite in subfolders to facilitate multiple languages.

My hosting provider uses the following Nginx config to fix the /wp-admin/ directives for the multisite environment:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
  rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
  rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;
  rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php) $2 last;
}
```

There is no main subsite defined, so I've put up a redirect for the root URL to the main language subfolder:

```
location = / {
  return 301 https://$host/nl/;
}
```

All requests for the domain without a subfolder are redirected tot the primary subfolder (**/nl/**). This all seems tot work just fine, except for the **/wp-admin/** url. I have tried every regexp matching pattern I could think of to redirect **/wp-admin/** to **/nl/wp-admin/** while keeping the existing **/nl/wp-admin/** and **/en/wp-admin/** URL's, but nothing seems to be working. At one point I was able to redirect **/wp-admin/** to **/nl/wp-admin/**, but this resulted in /en/wp-admin/ also being redirected to **/nl/wp-admin/**.

So my question is; what regexp can I use to match */wp-admin/* only when requested from the root path?

Desired outcome would be:

```
/wp-admin/ > /nl/wp-admin/
/nl/wp-admin/ > do nothing
/en/wp-admin/ > do nothing
```

Comment: We cannot provide support for _shared_ web hosting, where you are not in control of the server.